# Drupal form_submit and default_value

Tags: drupal, form-submit, default-value

I have a simple form:

```
function mymodule_test_form(&$form_state, $nid) {
  form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Click me!',
  );
  $form['mymodule_status'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'myclass'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('mymodule_status', 0),
    '#options' => array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'),
  );
  return $form;
}

function mymodule_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  db_query("INSERT INTO {mymodule} (nid, uid, number, created) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, " . time() . ")", $nid, $user->uid, $status);
}
```

And in my node-contenttype.tpl.php file I print drupal_get_form('mymodule_test_form', $node->nid). BTW, is it the right way to print the drupal_get_form in the template? I tried adding the drupal_get_form to the hook_nodeapi view state, but nothing outputs, so I just ended up printing it in the template.

Another thing is the default value, I'm not sure how to use that. The variable_get always is 0. Do I need to create a custom query of my own and set that as my default value? I thought the default_value is automatically retrieved by drupal or something...

Hope I can get some help. Thanks.

Edit: Found out the node id is under: $form['#parameters'][2]

Comment: Do you want to add a page with a form or are you trying to modify the add/edit form of a content type?

Comment: The form is added on the node view page. So you won't see it when you actually edit the node.

Comment: Wade, you're talking about solutions (a form) but I don't know which problem you're solving. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Is this some kind of rating system? (In that case, why not use http://drupal.org/project/fivestar?)

Comment: Similar to fivestar, but something much more simple. Users will have a select menu which they can choose an option from it and submit the form. I have got that working so far, except now I need to get the default value. So far I also have this working by creating a custom query and setting the default value with the result of that query. However, I'm not sure if that is the right way to do it. I thought default_value is automatically stored somewhere I'm not aware of. So I've seen users use variable_get, but nothing returns from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use variable_get for accessing a value previously set with variable_set. So, variable_get isn't returning anything because there isn't a previously-set variable with the name mymodule_status. See  http://api.drupal.org/api/function/variable_get/6.

I'm not sure, but it seems like you want the default value to be the status previously set by the user if that user has already set it. You'll need to do a query for that case.

```
function mymodule_test_form(&$form_state, $nid) {
  global $user;
  form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Click me!',
  );

  $query = "SELECT number FROM {mymodule} WHERE nid = %d AND uid = %d";
  $result = db_query($query, $nid, $user->uid);

  if ($result) $status = db_result($result);
  if ($status) $default_value = $status;
  else $default_value = 0;

  $form['mymodule_status'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'myclass'),
    '#default_value' => $default_value,
    '#options' => array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Also in your submit function, you need to reference $form_state['values']['mymodule_status'] instead of $status.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand what the variable is for now. Thanks, exactly what I wanted to know. :)